# Question about edit rollbacks

Tags: discussion, editing

Regarding question: [Interview appointment letter](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91040/interview-appointment-letter)

The original question was hard to follow and the wording wasn't intuitive to read. My suggested edit changed the wording and presented the question in a concise answerable format and was approved.

Another user rolled back the edit `to include more of the original content, for clarity` and the question was subsequently closed for being `unclear what you're asking` .

Is rolling back edits that do not remove relevant information, just to have more 'original content' even if it makes the question unclear, a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the user who rolled back your edits might have been too hasty in saving the answer. Indeed, they went back and re-edited the question to make it more clear. The question is to date still closed since there are some details missing. Namely [the ones suggested by Dorothy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91040/interview-appointment-letter#comment218227_91040).